# Where is Organization Browser Web Part?

Tags: web-part, organization-browser

I’ve been trying to add an “Organization Browser” web part on our main portal site (http://whatever.sitehere.com) but for some reason, the web part isn’t there. It can’t be found under Social Collaboration section but when I go to “My Site”, the web part is present.

Is there a way to use the web part on our main portal site?

Note here. Our main portal site is using the same host as our "My Site."

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate the SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features.

Answer (score 3):

I could successfuly resolve same problem by activating PortalLayouts feature on a site collection

```
stsadm -o activateFeature -name "PortalLayouts" -url "http://testportal2013" –force
```

as described in [Some Social Collaboration Web Parts Missing?](http://www.brainlitter.com/2011/08/12/some-social-collaboration-web-parts-missing/) article by Sean Wallbridge.
My site collection was migrated from SP2007, via SP2010 to SP2013, and according to that article this could be the cause of the problem. Runnig this command made the Organization Browser webpart visible.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
http://www.tcscblog.com/2011/04/11/using-the-sharepoint-2010-organization-browser-in-another-web-application/

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site! Just a note that we need details in our answers, not just links. [Please read this.](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117/links-in-answers)