# Where is the Organization Browser Web Part?

Tags: web-part

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is Organization Browser Web Part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/where-is-organization-browser-web-part)

SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features is Activated. Also show up in Web Part gallery. Howerver, only 2 of the social collaboration wp shows up when adding a wp. The org browser is missing.

Comment: What version of SharePoint 2010 are you running? (standard, enterprise, etc...)

Comment: I am sorry. Yes maam. I am on SP 2010 (I think it's standard). Portal and Mysite are on different web application.

Comment: Actually, just verified and it's enterprise.

Comment: Sorry @Robert but this looks like a duplicate of a previous question. Can you please add a comment with your information in the [other thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/where-is-organization-browser-web-part)?

Answer (score 0):

The organization browser is designed to show a user's position in an organization chart based on their user profile information, and in particular the various reports fields that record the management relationship between individuals. This web part is normally rendered in a user profile page.

You require the SharePoint Server 2010 Standard SKU. You probably won't find it offered in the web part gallery by default, but you should be able to track it down if you use the "Add new web part" dialogue by clicking on the New button in the ribbon. I must admit I have never tried to use it outside the context of a user profile page.

Comment: I can see the web part in both system dev n test (and they are setup the exact same way production is)

Comment: Check you have the same features activated. If you go to web part gallery can you add it to the gallery? Is user profiles working? Not much else I can suggest from the info given.